# How to read current app version in Xcode 11 with script

Tags: ios, xcode, sh, build-settings, xcode11

Until **Xcode 11**, I used a script that reads the current app version (for the AppStore) and help me change the LaunchScreen since we can't use swift for that.

```
sourceFilePath="$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/App/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard"
versionNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")

sed -i .bak -e "/userLabel=\"APP_VERSION_LABEL\"/s/text=\"[^\"]*\"/text=\"v$versionNumber\"/" "$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/App/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard"
```

But in **Xcode 11** there is a new section inside the project's build settings called **Versioning**

[image]

And `CFBundleShortVersionString` automatically changed to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`. Xcode automatically handles that and **I don't want to change it manually to an static number** and let Xcode do it's work.

[image: 11]

So the question is how can I access this new `MARKETING_VERSION` and set it to my launchScreen label using **run script**?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use it like any other project variable:

```
sourceFilePath="$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/App/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard"
versionNumber="$MARKETING_VERSION"
buildNumber="$CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION"

sed -i .bak -e "/userLabel=\"APP_VERSION_LABEL\"/s/text=\"[^\"]*\"/text=\"v$versionNumber\"/" "$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/App/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard"
```

Comment: This is not working for me or I'm missing something.

Comment: Is there a way to print the current value of $MARKETING_VERSION also in the terminal?

Comment: @HansBondoka `echo "The marketing version is: $MARKETING_VERSION"`

Answer (score 49):

**Xcode 11-14**

In **terminal** or **bash script in your project** you can use:

**App version**

`xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep MARKETING_VERSION | tr -d 'MARKETING_VERSION ='           // will be displayed 1.1.6`

**Build version**

`xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION | tr -d 'CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION ='     // will be displayed 7`

Or (*don't forget to change **YouProjectName** to your project name*):

**App version**

`cat YouProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj | grep -m1 'MARKETING_VERSION' | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d ';' | tr -d ' '`

**Build version**

`cat YouProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj | grep -m1 'CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION' | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr -d ';' | tr -d ' '`

Or **slower method** (Thx [Joshua Kaden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1537816/joshua-kaden)):

**App version**

`xcodebuild -project YouProjectName.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep "MARKETING_VERSION" | sed 's/[ ]*MARKETING_VERSION = //'`

**Build version**

`xcodebuild -project YouProjectName.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION" | sed 's/[ ]*CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = //'`

Comment: This works great if you have multiple build schemes that you need to get their version numbers. Just pass `--scheme {SCHEME}` to in the xcodebuild command.

Comment: @SeanRobinson159 should be `-scheme {SCHEME}`, working along with `-workspace {name}.xcodeworkspace`

Comment: `cat` worked like charm! Good one!

Answer (score 20):

Couldn't find right answer on the internet, so I started digging.

Version and build numbers are displayed in `./PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` as MARKETING VERSION (MV) and CURRENT PROJECT VERSION (CPV).

[image: version number]

[image: build number]

I used **sed** to get the numbers. It finds **first occurrence** of MV or CPV, removes everything except the number, and returns result. In order for this to work, you need to do 2 things:

- navigate to projects root folder
- change PROJECTNAME to your project's name

Commands:

```
version_number=`sed -n '/MARKETING_VERSION/{s/MARKETING_VERSION = //;s/;//;s/^[[:space:]]*//;p;q;}' ./PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
build_number=`sed -n '/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION/{s/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = //;s/;//;s/^[[:space:]]*//;p;q;}' ./PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
```

Result:

[image: version and build numbers]

Note: If you have more targets in your workspace with different version and build numbers, this might or might not work for you, because it stops on first occurrence. In that case, good luck :)

Comment: Nice. Works for me.

Comment: You should use `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` instead on direct reading project file

Comment: `xcodebuild -project ThreeOneOne.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | grep "MARKETING_VERSION" | sed 's/[ ]*MARKETING_VERSION = //'`

Comment: Tried with -showBuildSettings on three projects and not getting the MARKETING_VERSION, nor CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION. If you are getting it, thumbs up, go with it :)

Comment: @Babac hope you're already solved the problem. The reason you cannot obtain the `MARKETING_VERSION` is that you are working in a workspace instead of a project (hinted by you have three projects in hand). To get the version, you can issue this command: `xcodebuild -workspace YourName.xcodeworkspace -scheme YourSchemeName -showBuildSettings | grep "MARKETING_VERSION"`

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the first occurrence where its a number and not "$(inherited)"

Answer (score 6):

I miss here a solution for multiple targets and configurations:

```
xcodebuild -target <target> -configuration <configuaration> -showBuildSettings  | grep -i 'MARKETING_VERSION' | sed 's/[ ]*MARKETING_VERSION = //'
```

- **target**: the name of the target
- **configuration**: Release, Debug

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

If you use **Bitrise** then the following script will save you:

## Extracting App Marketing Version

`` envman add --key=APP_VERSION_NO --value=`sed -n '/MARKETING_VERSION/{s/MARKETING_VERSION = //;s/;//;s/^[[:space:]]*//;p;q;}' ./${PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT_XCODEPROJ_FILE}/project.pbxproj` ``

## Extracting App Build Number

Extract the Build Number from xcodeproj file only if you use **Apple Generic** versioning system otherwise extract the Build Number from the XCode project info.plist file.

Note: The following script extracts the Build Number from the xcodeproj file.

`` envman add --key=APP_BUILD_NO --value=`sed -n '/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION/{s/CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = //;s/;//;s/^[[:space:]]*//;p;q;}' ./${PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT_XCODEPROJ_FILE}/project.pbxproj` ``

### Printing to console:

`envman run bash -c 'echo "App Version: $APP_VERSION_NO"'`

`envman run bash -c 'echo "App Build No: $APP_BUILD_NO"'`

Thanks to the answer by @babac

Answer (score 2):

Most voted answers by now show how to extract the value through `sed` and further tools in the chain. Thought to provide a (simpler?) solution just through `awk`.

Just to give a little bit of context, following one-liner shows the culprit row:

```sh
xcodebuild -project MyProj/MyProj.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | awk '/MARKETING_VERSION/ { print }'

# output
    MARKETING_VERSION = 0.0.1
```

Default awk field separator should be the space, and so it's just a matter of extracting the third field (*MARKETING_VERSION* is first, the equal sign is second):

```sh
xcodebuild -project MyProj/MyProj.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings | awk '/MARKETING_VERSION/ { print $3 }'

# output
0.0.1
```

HTH

Comment: why I get an error said `DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-19450/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:373`

Comment: Hi @user2027712. With info provided, I have no idea. I suggest you open a dedicated question for that, providing all needed context, more information, etc. Better yet, if you haven't done already, try searching for that error message on the web. It does not look like an error coming from command line, which is the main topic of this answer. There must be something else wrong in your Xcode build I guess.

Answer (score 1):

How about saving a value to CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION ? did anyone managed to do this?

I can get the value like

```
buildNumber=$CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION
```

but this doesn't work:

```
CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=""    or   $CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=""
```

In my case I'm trying to set it to ""

This line doesn't set the CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION field too

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$appInfoPlist"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project is set up to use **Apple Generic Versioning** then you may use this command:

```
agvtool what-marketing-version -terse1
```

More info on how to set up **AGV** can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html).

Comment: This is actually a cleaner way if the version is set in the Info.plist file rather than in build settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js: there is [xcode package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xcode). Example of usage:

```
const xcode = require('xcode');

const project = xcode.project('ios/PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj').parse(() => {
  const config = project.pbxXCBuildConfigurationSection();
  const releaseScheme = Object.keys(config).find(key => config[key].name === 'Release');

  const version = config[releaseScheme].buildSettings.MARKETING_VERSION;
});
```

Previously I used the `plist` package, but with latest xCode changes it became outdated, since I'm not able to extract a version from `Info.plist` for React Native projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and made it work by displaying MARKETING_VERSION itself:

```
version="$MARKETING_VERSION"
version+=" ("
version+=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $SRCROOT/MyApp/Info.plist`
version+=")"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$SRCROOT/MyApp/Settings.bundle/Root.plist" -c "set PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue $version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a framework with this scenario:

- A workspace
- A framework target
- An aggregate target with 2 external scripts:

  - one for build a fat framework
  - other for prepare the release framework

The key is that *in XCode 11 the aggregate framework script doesn't get run environment variables for other workspace targets* so it's impossible to read the $MARKETING_VERSION from my framework target.

So the solution that works for me has been ***use PlistBuddy specifying the Info.plist result of the framework target build*** in this way:

```
FAT_FRAMEWORK="${SRCROOT}/build/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
BUILD_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${FAT_FRAMEWORK}/Info.plist")
VERSION_NUMBER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${FAT_FRAMEWORK}/Info.plist")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jq` because `xcodebuild` has `-json` option.

```
❯ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -json 2>/dev/null | jq '.[0].buildSettings.MARKETING_VERSION'
"0.1.0"
```

```
❯ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -json 2>/dev/null | jq '.[0].buildSettings.CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION'
"1"
```

`jq -r` prints raw value:

```
❯ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -json 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.[0].buildSettings.MARKETING_VERSION'
0.1.0
```

```
❯ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -json 2>/dev/null | jq -r '.[0].buildSettings.CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION'
1
```

Comment: What is `jq`? There's nothing on my Mac named `jq`.

Comment: It is a well-known JSON processing OSS software. jq is not installed by default. https://github.com/jqlang/jq / You may use any scripting language that can process JSON, or you may install jq with Homebrew.

Comment: It would be helpful to put that info in your answer.