# Settings.bundle version number is updating as $(MARKETING_VERSION)

Tags: ios, scripting, versioning, xcode11, settings.bundle

I have an app which was setting versions automatically when I incremented from

**XCode > General > Version**.

But recently I have updated XCode to 11.0 and seems the script is not working as expected:

```
version=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" $SRCROOT/MyApp/Info.plist`
version+=" ("
version+=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $SRCROOT/MyApp/Info.plist`
version+=")"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$SRCROOT/MyApp/Settings.bundle/Root.plist" -c "set PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue $version"
```

Above script suppose to automatically update version and would have been visible in Settings > App.

[image]

But the question is there any change need to be done for this script to make automatically update version number from XCode?

Currently it is being replaced by scripts as $(MARKETING_VERSION) when version is incremented from **XCode > General > Version** which is not correct.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722677/how-to-read-current-app-version-in-xcode-11-with-script) what you are looking for? [how-to-read-current-app-version-in-xcode-11-with-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722677/how-to-read-current-app-version-in-xcode-11-with-script)

Comment: It worked by doing some changes as mentioned in my answer. But I am not sure if it is good idea to extract from storyboard as you are doing.

Comment: That's not extracting **from** storyboard. That replacing it.

Comment: You are not at all using sourceFilePath isn't it?

Comment: No (mistake), but that is not part of the issue ;)

Comment: Yeah. Found new thing today that we can get version number from MARKETING_VERSION ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked by displaying MARKETING_VERSION itself: Thanks @dgimb and @Mojtaba Hosseini for your answers.

```
version="$MARKETING_VERSION"
version+=" ("
version+=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $SRCROOT/MyApp/Info.plist`
version+=")"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$SRCROOT/MyApp/Settings.bundle/Root.plist" -c "set PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue $version"
```

Comment: I have an error message *Set: Entry, "PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue", Does Not Exist
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code*

Comment: Can you share the script.

Answer (score 10):

The version string `$MARKETING_VERSION` as well as build number `$CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` are now exposed as environment variable during the build process as they are now persisted in the `.pbxproj` configuration.

You should be able to achieve what you want like this:

```
version="$MARKETING_VERSION ($CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$SRCROOT/MyApp/Settings.bundle/Root.plist" -c "set PreferenceSpecifiers:1:DefaultValue $version"
```

Comment: $CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION do not display anything. However version is displayed in $MARKETING_VERSION.