# How to set the build number in Bitrise with the new XCode project layout

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, bitrise

As newer Xcode projects do not put the version and build numbers any more into the Info.plist, but rather it's located in the project files.

How can I set the build number in a CI like Bitrise?

Comment: is [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56722677/5623035) what you are looking for?

Comment: This is interesting on now to read it, but I need to write it

Answer (score 1):

I am changing the iOS build number like this using Bitrise script step.

I added one script step which can change the version number and build number using the Xcode command. In this, I saved the build number an Environment variable, and the version number it will take from the Bitrise build number. I am appending .21.21 in Bitrise version number. Exam. If bitrise build number is 8 then the version will be 8.21.21.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oTPg.png

If you are using manual trigger then you can change bitrise version.[image]

Please check this apple document to update the version.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html

Hope you will find this helpful.